# logoutid not available in implicit flow with identity server4

Tags: asp.net-identity, logout, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

hi I am using identity server 4 implicit flow,

I am able to perform login and logout using oidc-client.js library,

but when logout on the identity server -- > account controller --> Logout action
parameter "logoutid" is receiving null due to which I cannot get the information about client.

Samples provided by the identity team has a working example where logoutid is available. Only difference with the sample is I am using ASP.Net identity which shouldn't be an issue.

can any one help me solve the issue?

This issue is only for Implicit flow JavaScript application, I am receiving logoutid when working with MVC application.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked that your postLogoutRedirectUri is in the list of allowable postLogoutRedirectUris - If you don't know then look at your identity server logging - That should tell you why.

idsr looks up this url before handing off the controller method.