# IdentityServer logoutId is null

Tags: identityserver4

I can't get the PostLogoutRedirectUri from IdentityServer4 because logoutId on my Logout action is always null. I checked and the PostLogoutRedirectUris property has the same exact url I'm sending and it still won't work, logoutId is always null.

After researching a little bit deeper I found out one of the errors being thrown are due to `IsActiveContext` not being active:

- source: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/Validation/Default/TokenValidator.cs#L123

I just couldn't find the process to fix it and confirm if this is the only problem.

Logs:

[image]

Code:

[image]

`ClientStore`:

```
var client = new Client
{
    ClientId = application.Key,
    ClientName = application.Description,
    AllowedGrantTypes = grantType,
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
        "role",
        "openIdConnectClient"
    },
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    RedirectUris = new List<string> { application.Url },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> { $"{application.Url}" },
    RequireConsent = false,
    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> { new Secret(application.Key.Sha256()) }
};
```

Request:

[image]

I've read a lot of related questions such as, but not limited to:

- [logoutid not available in implicit flow with identity server4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494644/logoutid-not-available-in-implicit-flow-with-identity-server4)
- [IdentityServer4 PostLogoutRedirectUri null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44684664/identityserver4-postlogoutredirecturi-null)
- [IdentityServer4 PostLogoutRedirectUri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117283/identityserver4-postlogoutredirecturi?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/992

Comment: Is it present with the correct `ClientId` in the `ClientPostLogoutRedirectUris` table?

Comment: @WimOmbelets hi, do you mean Client.PostLogoutRedirectUris? If so, yes, it is there. I'm going to update my question with code from ClientStore.

Comment: @WimOmbelets updated.

Comment: @eestein I had exactly the same problem and managed to solve it by setting SaveToken true in the options of my resource api.

`services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AuthConfig:AuthorityEndpoint");
                    options.ApiName = "someapi";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                    options.SaveToken = true;
                });`

Comment: I had exactly the same issue and in my case the root cause was the extra slash at the end of the `postLogoutRedirectUri` in the IDM config, while in the request to `/connect/endsession` the `postLogoutRedirectUri` was without the slash.